# strip comments with markers

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am working on [this Codewars problem](https://www.codewars.com/kata/51c8e37cee245da6b40000bd/train/javascript) and this is the solution I came up with. The return looks exactly like what is expected, but it's saying it's wrong.

This is the failed test return:
Returned 'apples, pears
grapes
bananas' but expected 'apples, pears
grapes
bananas'

Am I losing it? Is it something w/ whitespace for the second line my eyes aren't seeing?

```
function solution(input, markers) {
  let regex = new RegExp(markers.join("|"), "g")
  
  return input.replace(regex, "-").replace(/-(.*)/g, "").trimRight()
};
```

Comment: To improve the question, can you describe the functional goal of the regex in the question, not on the end of a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First line in your result is not trimmed.

`trimRight()` for multiline input deletes whitespace symbols only at the end of last line.

You need to iterate by lines and trim them independently.